# Why Images have 403 error at first time loading of my website?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, http-status-code-403

When I load the website for the first time some images not loading and they have 403 error. after refreshing the page they are loading correctly. It happens when I load the site on https version.
This is the exception that I get in chrome :
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()

Permission of the images folder has read option.
I also have tried app.UseStaticFiles(); but it didn't work.
Click [here](https://kejwanco.com) (https://kejwanco.com) to see the website

Comment: If your request filter or IP restriction on server node or site node have any limitation with unspecified clients, it could return a 403 forbidden. So please check IP address and domain restriction.

Comment: Share us your current `Startup.cs`. Have you used `app.UseStaticFiles()` before `app.UseAuthentication();`. Does the image stored in `wwwroot` folder?

Comment: Yes, I've done that.